# Capture ANSI escape sequence response with LUA

Tags: lua, nodemcu, ansi-escape

I'm using and ESP8266 with Nodemcu to communicate with a serial terminal using Putty.
Using escape sequences like referenced in these questions:

[Read ANSI escape from terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36929209/read-ansi-escape-from-terminal)

[How do I determine size of ANSI terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35688348/how-do-i-determine-size-of-ansi-terminal)

List of escape sequences
https://vt100.net/docs/vt100-ug/chapter3.html

I am trying to read back an escape sequence that is a reply to find the cursor position using LUA. I don't seem to be getting a visible reply (expected), but I also don't seem to get anything. Everything except the reply seems to work.

What am I doing wrong, how can I capture the response?

```
  -- Clear screen
  uart.write(0, "\033[2J")

  -- Setup event handler callback to read data from terminal
  -- Control sequence is terminated with an 'R'
  -- I'm replacing ESC in the reply so that I can hopefully get a visible reply like _[25;80R

  uart.on("data", 0, function(data)
    if data ~= 'R' then
      uart.write(0, data)
    end
    if data == '\033' then
      uart.write(0, "_")
    end
  end, 0)

  -- ESC = \033
  
  -- cursorpos(v,h) CUP    Move cursor to screen location v,h     ^[[<v>;<h>H
  uart.write(0, "\033[20;20H")
  
  uart.write(0, "\033[6n")

  -- Response:
  -- cursorpos CPR         Response: cursor is at v,h          ^[<v>;<h>R
```

Comment: https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/release/modules/uart/

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I had a syntax error with my uart read handler.
I changed the /033 for ESC to CTRL-v[
and the condition for my IF statement. I'm not sure why the \033 didn't work.

For testing, I also changed the 20;20 part to 200;200 just to see how that worked and it gave the correct expected response: _[45;157R

I changed the code from:

```
  uart.on("data", 0, function(data)
    if data ~= 'R' then
      uart.write(0, data)
    end
    if data == '\033' then
      uart.write(0, "_")
    end
  end, 0)
```

To:

```
 uart.on("data", 0, function(data)
 if data == '\27' then 
   uart.write(0,"_")
 else
   uart.write(0, data) end end, 0)
```

Comment: In Lua you should write `"\27[6n"` instead of `"\033[6n"`