# Capture ANSI escape sequence response using Micropython ESP8266

Tags: esp8266, micropython

I'm using an ESP8266 with Micropython to communicate with a serial terminal using Putty. Using escape sequences like referenced in these questions:

[Read ANSI escape from terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36929209/read-ansi-escape-from-terminal)

[How do I determine size of ANSI terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35688348/how-do-i-determine-size-of-ansi-terminal)

List of escape sequences https://vt100.net/docs/vt100-ug/chapter3.html

I am trying to read back an escape sequence that is a reply to find the cursor position.
I can see the response in the terminal, but I need to capture it so I can parse it. I'm familiar with Python, but a complete noob with Micropython and the ESP8266 (ESP01). I'm using the webrepl to upload the code. I saw this and I'm not sure if it's related: https://forum.micropython.org/viewtopic.php?t=5359

I've tried running my code without webrepl connected, but it still didn't work.

What am I doing wrong, how can I capture the response?

Depending on the terminal size, the response should be something like below, the stuff before the ; will not be visible.
^[[45;157R

```
#import esp
import network
import machine
from machine import UART

uart = UART(0, 115200)

x=uart.write("\033[500;500H\033[6n")
if uart.any():
  print(":> ", uart.read())
```

EDIT: Tried example from this link https://forum.micropython.org/viewtopic.php?t=5359#p30867

No luck with that either (yes, I know it's blocking). Here if I type the letter 'R', it drops out of the loop, but it's not catching the output from the escape sequence.

```
from machine import UART
import machine
import network
import uos

uos.dupterm(None, 1)
uart = UART(0, 115200)

charbuf = None

uart.write("\033[500;500H\033[6n")

while charbuf != b"R":
  if uart.any():
    charbuf = uart.read()
    uart.write(charbuf)
uos.dupterm(UART(0, 115200), 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Solving this was a nightmare, the WebRepl console replication has been the bane of my existence and probably many others. I tried multiple read() methods and they all failed.

```
uart.read()
sys.stdin.read()
sys.stdin.buffer.read()
```

Those were in combination of enabling/disabling the console duplication for webrepl.
The incantation that finally worked for me is below. See inline comments for more details.

```
import machine
import network
#import sys
import uos
from machine import UART

uos.dupterm(None, 1)  # Disable console duplication for Webrepl
uart = UART(0, 115200, timeout=100, timeout_char=100)  #Instantiate uart, increase timeout for good measure
uart.write("\033[2J\033[1;1f") # Clear screen
uart.write("\033[500;500H\033[6n") # Move cursor to bottom right, send query.

# Wait for uart to collect response. This will block further execution until we get a reply.
while True:
  if uart.any() != 0:
    break

uos.dupterm(UART(0, 115200), 1)  # Re-enable console redirection so print() will work

# Read the uart buffer with response, convert from binary to string, replace ESC character.
# First ^ gets eaten somewhere!
buf = str(uart.read(), 'UTF-8').replace('\x1b', '^^[')

if len(buf) > 0:  # If response isn't empty, print buffer
  print(buf)
```

This is the Output:

```
^[[43;157R
```